# Error after updating targetSDK version - ListView not working: interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a NameDay app in the App Store that was using an Android SDK <26. Since Google wants to make every app change its TargetSDK at least to 26 in order to continue being able to update, I wanted to change my app in order to satisfy Google's needs.

Changed the proper fields regarding the SDK, but now I get a crash when I try to run the app in the emulator.

**App MainActivity:**
The main activity of the app searches the database and gets all the names that celebrate today and shows them. Below that textview, i have a listview that compares the names that celebrate today to your contacts, and shows the contacts celebrating their name day in order to be able to call or send an sms.

The error I get is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.duk3r.eortologio2, PID: 9577
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
    at com.duk3r.eortologio2.LazyAdapter.getCount(LazyAdapter.java:32)
    at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AdapterView.java:836)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AbsListView.java:6414)
    at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
    at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseAdapter.java:50)
    at com.duk3r.eortologio2.LazyAdapter.setItems(LazyAdapter.java:45)
    at com.duk3r.eortologio2.MainActivity$LoadItemsTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:498)
    at com.duk3r.eortologio2.MainActivity$LoadItemsTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:480)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

The main files that appear in the error messages are:

**[MainActivity.java](https://pastebin.com/nHzd0X45)**

and **[LazyAdapter.java](https://pastebin.com/gxH4RJ83)**

I read similar posts here in StackOverflow and they say that getCount() returns null and crashes the app. The thing is that I didn't change and code regarding the adapters or/and the main activity, and the app was working before. Did Google change something in the latest SDKs?

Thanks in advance.

Update: The app works fine with targetSDK 27 in an emulator with API 23, just tried it again. When I switch to an emulator with SDK >26, it crashes on startup when it tries to check the listview code.

Comment: Your `ListData.getData` must have thrown an exception, so your adapter ends up setting `null` to its items. Could you check your stack trace again please?

Comment: You is trying get a value in a empty list. You must add content to your list.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was that from API 23 and forth, the declared permissions in the Android Manifest don't really matter. You have to ask for the permissions on the fly, if you want it to work on api >23.

Made it work with this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {

    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) ==
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    System.out.println("Permission Granted");
    } else {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

    }
}
```

You have to ask for each permission you need separately, so that the app continues to work with no problem.